# Qual a significado da expressão "o que é mais"?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

> Assim como no fogo se prova o ouro e a prata, assim também nessa longa
>   hora, em que o pai ou marido leva a bocejar, coçar a cabeça, passear
>   pela sala e Consultar o relógio, fica-lhe provada a santa virtude da
>   paciência, e, **o que é mais**, são-lhe de justiça descontados boa meia
>   dúzia de seus pequenos pecados.

Qual o significado da expressão "o que é mais" no trecho acima? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"o que é mais"** é pouco usado em pt-BR. Eu diria  **"além do mais"**, que é idiomático e de uso corrente.

> - ["além do mais"](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/al%C3%A9m%20do%20mais) - expressão usada para acrescentar algo ao que já foi dito. = além disso, aliás, ademais.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui, "o que é mais" parece indicar `a maior/melhor parte` ou `melhor ainda`: "fica-lhe provada a virtude e, *melhor ainda*, lhe são descontados pecados".

Apenas `mais`, sozinho, significaria nesse contexto `além disso`, `adicionalmente`: "fica-lhe provada a virtude e, *além disso*, lhe são descontados pecados". Dado o estilo da escrita, imagino ser possível, embora menos provável que a sugestão do parágrafo acima, que "o que é mais" seja uma versão floreada de "mais".